# Is it possible to gather the licenses in one server?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, licensing, microsoft-office-2010

How can servers take licences from one server? How about MS office licenses (more than 300) could be installed on the clients, I know there is a way but what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Could you explain what you are asking in more detail?  Hard to tell what you are asking.

Comment: There 300 computers in a certain domaine, how is it possible to assign them a MS office license automatically without having to install the licenses one by one...

Comment: Again, what you're saying doesn't make sense. Anyone with 300 PCs with office would have a volume license with the same license on every machine. You put a copy of office on a server, generate an msp file with your options preselected and you enter the license. When you install its automatic, no questions, no license to enter. Activation is automatic.  You can push out office with a script or at logon. What are you trying to do? Hopefully its not install 300 copies of office retail?

Comment: Since i'm a newbie, I would be thankfull if you could share with me some documentation about how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

For Office 2010, volume license is managed through [KMS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772269.aspx) role. It's just a 2008 Server to which your give KMS keys. Same for Windows 7.

You can use [VAMT](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11936) to scan your computers and gather license info

Volume imply Microsoft contract with your company and not buying license in the box at the local store